# Length of the diagonal of a "dented triangle"

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, triangles, metric-geometry

Consider a "dented triangle" like in this picture:
[image]
(the angle $\alpha$ is larger than $\pi$). Compare it with an actual triangle $\triangle\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}$ with sidelengths $a, b$ and $c = c' + c''$, with a point $\bar{X}$ on the side of length $c$ at distances $c'$ and $c''$ of the respective endpoints. I need to show that 
$$
d(\bar{C}, \bar{X}) \geq d(C, X)
$$
($d$ denotes distance).
I do not only need this for a euclidean triangle, but also for hyperbolic and spherical triangles (in the last case maybe you need $a, b \leq \pi/2$)

**Some background:** This is the last (and I thought easiest) step in the proof of a "reverse" Toponogov comparison theorem which states that under an upper curvature bound on a Riemannian manifold triangles are "thinner" than the corresponding comparison triangles.

**Ideas so far**: By the corresponding cosine laws it is equivalent to show that the angle at $\bar{A}$ is larger than the one at $A$.
Also if both $a > c''$ and $b > c'$ then (at least in the euclidean case) it is easy to prove since one of the two angles at $X$ has to decrease when passing to the "straight triangle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation :** $i) \ [xy]$ is a line segment between $x$ and $y$

$ii)\ |A-B|$ is a distance between $A$ and $B$

**Proof :** Assume that $\Delta\ \overline{C}\overline{B}\overline{A}$ is a
triangle s.t. $|\overline{C}-\overline{B}|=|C-B|,\
|\overline{C}-\overline{A}|=|C-A|,\
|\overline{B}-\overline{A}|=c'+c'' $

Consider a point $A'$ s.t. a
line segment $[BA']$ contains $X$ and $|X-A'|=|X-A|$.

Since $\alpha >\pi$, then $\angle\ CXA > \angle \ CXA'$

Hence $|C-A|>|C-A'|\ \ast$. In a triangle $\Delta\ CBA'$, by
$\ast$, then $\angle\ CBA' <\angle\
 \overline{C}
\overline{B}\overline{A}\ \ast\ast$

Hence from $\ast\ast$, we complete the proof.

**Reference :** Alexandrov Lemma in the book From Euclid to Alexandrov; a guided tour - Petrunin and Yashinski